# background-attachment: fixed not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, slick.js, background-attachment

I have the following site:
https://dasproject.netlify.com/lisa/
edit: doesn’t have the problem any more

When opening it in Chrome, the cover-image is fixed, as it should be, but when opening in Firefox, the background-attachment: fixed doesn't work

What I know so far:
The image is inside a slider, which uses `transform: translate3d()`. That's what breaks the background-attachment, but I have no idea how to fix it (One obvious would be to remove the slider, but I'm aiming for something simpler)

Any thoughts why?
I've tried a lot …
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the css prefixes?

Comment: Which prefixes should I use? I works if I put the image outside of the silider, so I guess that's not the problem

Comment: I've solved it for now by removing the `transform: translate3d()`, but I still don't know the answer

Answer (score 2):

The very first moment I turn off `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)` in Firefox developer tools, I get my `background-attachment: fixed` instantly back to normal.

It's Firefox 57 (Quantum, 64-bit) on Windows 7.

No other info or idea why is this happening though. No sustainable theory other than this has to be a bug.